# Multiple Where Clauses as Separate Columns

Tags: sql

I have a sales order table that goes:

```
SALESORDERCODE  ITEMCODE    WAREHOUSECODE
SO-605338      ITEM-003200      MAIN
SO-605338      ITEM-016328      PFC
```

I also have an inventory table that goes:

```
WAREHOUSECODE   ITEMCODE    UNITSINSTOCK
MAIN            ITEM-003200     1
MAIN            ITEM-016328     2
PFC             ITEM-016328     3
PFC             ITEM-003200     4
```

Can anyone help me with a series of joins that will output:

```
SALESORDERCODE  ITEMCODE    UNITS IN MAIN   UNITS IN PFC
SO-605338      ITEM-003200         1             3
SO-605338      ITEM-016328         2             4
```

I can write a `WHERE` clause that will output either MAIN or PFC, but I need to columns side by side.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Shouldn't 003200 have 4 units in PFC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's limited to just those two, you can use a case statement: 
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a92c/1)

```
select
SO.SalesOrderCode
,I.ITEMCODE
,sum(case when I.WAREHOUSECODE = 'MAIN' then  I.UNITSINSTOCK else 0 end) as MAIN
,sum(case when I.WAREHOUSECODE = 'PFC' then  I.UNITSINSTOCK else 0 end)
from
SalesOrder SO
inner join Inventory I
  ON SO.ITEMCODE = I.ITEMCODE
group by
SO.SalesOrderCode,
I.ITEMCODE
```

Otherwise, depending on your RDBMS platform, you may be able to look into pivoting.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the result using 2 JOINs on your `INVENTORY` table - one join for each `WarehouseCode` that you want in a column:

```
select 
  so.SALESORDERCODE,
  so.ITEMCODE,
  i_main.UNITSINSTOCK UnitsInMain,
  i_pfc.UNITSINSTOCK UnitsInPFC
from SalesOrder so
left join Inventory i_main
  on so.ItemCode = i_main.ItemCode
  and i_main.WAREHOUSECODE = 'Main'
left join Inventory i_pfc
  on so.ItemCode = i_pfc.ItemCode
  and i_pfc.WAREHOUSECODE = 'PFC';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/586c5/4).  You'll notice that when you LEFT JOIN on the `INVENTORY` table you will include the filter for the `WarehouseCode` that you want to return.

It's not exactly clear if you need a total of the units in each Warehouse, if so then this could be rewritten using an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select
  so.SALESORDERCODE,
  so.ITEMCODE,
  sum(case when i.WAREHOUSECODE = 'Main' then i.UNITSINSTOCK end) UnitsInMain,
  sum(case when i.WAREHOUSECODE = 'PFC' then i.UNITSINSTOCK end) UnitsInPFC
from SalesOrder so
left join Inventory i
  on so.ItemCode = i.ItemCode
group by so.SALESORDERCODE,
  so.ITEMCODE;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/586c5/12/0)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it works without an SQL fiddle, but here is my first thought:

```
select sot.SALESORDERCODE,sot.ITEMCODE, sum(main.UNITSINSTOCK), sum(pfc.UNITSINSTOCK)
from sales_order_table sot
left join inventory_table main on sot.ITEMCODE=main.ITEMCODE and main.WAREHOUSECODE='MAIN'
left join inventory_table pfc on sot.ITEMCODE=pfc.ITEMCODE and pfc.WAREHOUSECODE='PFC'
group by sot.SALESORDERCODE,sot.ITEMCODE
```

if the same product is in the inventory table twice for main or pfc it sums. What about other warehouse codes? do we need a pivot here?

Comment: This is correct but from the desired result it doesn't look like they want to aggregate the `UnitsInStock`, that part is not clear. This could also be written slightly different using an aggregate/CASE and a single join.